# How to check the version of Qt in a .pro file?

Tags: qt

I want to check the version of Qt in the pro file so I can import the suitable library. I made this code but it doesn't work

```
greaterThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 4) {
    LIBS += -L/usr/include -lquazip -lz
} else {
    LIBS += -L/usr/include -lquazip-qt5 -lz
}
```

I want to import the lquazip library if qt version is 5.5.x and lquazip-qt5 if the version equals to 5.4.x.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `-qt5` version for all 5.x Qt versions?

Comment: No since qt 5.5, the name of the libquazip library has changed. -qt5 version doesn't work anymore

Comment: The name of the quazip library is what the package maintainer gave it, so you should probably be checking for distro version or whatever, or employ some generic configuration mechanism. Qt version doesn't have anything to do with it, although it might be the case that on your particular distro quazip name changed happened at the same time the quazip library name was changed too.

Comment: Try to print diagnostic `message`s  in if-else branches. If they work properly, a problem is somewhere else.

Comment: How i can print diagnostic message, I create a simple application with  `qDebug()<<qVersion();` and it shows 5.5.1 but my application searchs always lquazip-qt5

Comment: @Dababi I mean `greaterThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 4) {
message(Greater than 5.4.x)...`

Comment: yes it worked. I compiled my project with qt 5.4.2 under ubuntu 15 and i copied the executable to ubuntu 16 that runs qt 5.5.1 but the executable doesn't run. when i type ldd i see that it always search lquazip-qt5

Comment: Thats what you linked against. What you are trying to achive is using another version determined on runtime. You would have to use QLibrary for that and not link during compile time. The pro file gets evaluated during compile time only and does not exist during runtime anymore. Actually Sergey is pointing to the real problem.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianLange. This is the solution